# Why does Firefox say it "can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:3000/" after successful return upgrade request?

Tags: javascript, c++, websocket, poco-libraries

I wrote a program in c++ to upgrade an HTTP session to a WebSocket. The server correctly receives the upgrade request, and responds with 101 switching protocols. Firefox receives the 101 response, but in the console claims it couldn't connect. Here's the full output in Firefox.

[image: Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:3000/.]

The interesting thing is, in the network tab you can see the 101 response come in so it did establish an HTTP connection, the server got it, accepted it, tried to upgrade, and sent an upgrade response, but it's at that point that firefox doesn't upgrade to a WebSocket and prints the error.[image]

I tried in Google Chrome as well. Similar error, but a bit more detail. `WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Sent non-empty 'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol' header but no response was received`

My code c++ hangs on the while loop, no errors thrown, which I think means it thinks the connection is still working?

I did notice it's sending Sec-Websocket-Protocol, even though I only asked for `ws`, not `wss`. Do chrome and firefox disallow non secure websockets? Or am I missing something in my code?

C++:

```cpp
#define PORT (unsigned short) 3000
#define MAX_BUF 2048

int main()
{
    Poco::Net::ServerSocket x(PORT);
    Poco::Timespan timeout(25000000);
    if (x.poll(timeout, 1)) {
        Poco::Net::StreamSocket ss = x.acceptConnection();
        Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::Net::HTTPServerParams> params = new Poco::Net::HTTPServerParams();
        Poco::Net::HTTPServerSession sess(ss,params);
        Poco::Net::HTTPServerResponseImpl res(sess);
        Poco::Net::HTTPServerRequestImpl req(res, sess, params);
        if (req.getMethod()=="GET" && req.get("Upgrade")=="websocket") {
            Poco::Net::WebSocket webSock(req,res);
            while (!webSock.available());
            char buf[MAX_BUF];
            memset(buf,0,MAX_BUF);
            int flags = 0;
            webSock.sendFrame("Hello, World!\n",15);
            webSock.receiveFrame(buf,MAX_BUF,flags);
            printf("received %s\n",buf);
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("Timeout!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    webSoc = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3000");
    webSoc.onopen = function (event) {
        $("#c").click(function () {
            console.log("Sending 'Hello, World!'");
            webSoc.send("Hello, World!\n");
        });
    }
});
```

I've tried `new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3000")` with and without the `echo-protocol` parameter, because I read it in an answer to a question I didn't understand, which I can't find now.

Comment: I see your server *preparing* a response, but where is it actually being *sent* back to the client? Chrome is very clear in saying that no response is being received.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Well that's the funny part. The error says no response was received, but the network tab shows a 101 response from the server. The response comes from the [WebSocket Constructor](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.WebSocket.html).  It "completes the handshake by sending a proper 101 response."

Comment: But the screenshot you provided does not show any response headers. So it is difficult for people here to validate what you are seeing.

Comment: You are indeed correct. Let me add another screen shot. Thanks!